# How can I filter through what is displayed with useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, api, use-effect

I am a bit lost on what to do for the next step. I have managed to display the content but I can't seem to get it to filter with a click. It was easy enough to do with a different api , i followed webdevsimplified but this i can't work out and I am at my wits end!

All I want is to filter through the mapped api. for example if I check 3, it should show me only 3 starRating. Can anybody offer me some advice please.

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header';
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';



export default function App() {
  const [hotelRooms, setHotelRooms] = useState([]);

 
 
  const fetchHotels = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/hotels?collection-id=OBMNG')
    const hotels = await res.json()
    
    const hotelRooms = []

    for(const hotel of hotels) {
      const res = await fetch(`https://obmng.dbm.guestline.net/api/roomRates/OBMNG/${hotel.id}`)
      const info = await res.json()
      hotelRooms.push({ hotel, rooms: info.rooms })
    }

    setHotelRooms(hotelRooms)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHotels()
    
    
  }, [])

 
 
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <Header/>
     
      {
        hotelRooms.map(h => (
          
          <div>

          <input value={"1"} type="checkbox" onChange={}/>
          <input value={"Adults"}type="checkbox" onChange={}/>
          
          
            <h2> Name: {h.hotel.name}</h2>
            <p> Description: {h.hotel.description}</p>
            <p> Rating: {h.hotel.starRating}</p>
            <p> Postcode: {h.hotel.postcode}</p>
            <p> City: {h.hotel.town}</p>
            <img src={h.hotel.images}/>
            
                               

            <p style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Rooms:</p>
            {
             h.rooms.map(room => (
               <div>
               <h5>Occupancy</h5>
               
               <div> Adults: {room.occupancy.maxAdults}</div>
               <div> Children: {room.occupancy.maxChildren}</div>
               <div> Maximum guests: {room.occupancy.maxOverall}</div>
                <div> Room type: {room.name}</div>
                <img src={room.images}/>
               </div>
             ))
            }
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a state that saves the filtered properties.

```js
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ ratings: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] });
```

When you show the checkboxes add a name to them and the respective values.
Remember when you use `.map` in render, add an unique key to the out most tag.

```js
<div>
  {["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].map((star) => (
    <div key={"input-" + star}>
      <input
        id={"rated" + star}
        value={star}
        name="ratings"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={filter.ratings.includes(star)}
        onChange={handleRatingFilter}
      />
      <label htmlFor={"rated" + star}>Rated {star} star</label>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Now in the `onChange` handler, update the state according to the checkboxes:

```js
const handleRatingFilter = (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    // adding value
    const temp = [...filter.ratings];
    temp.push(e.target.value);
    setFilter({ ...filter, ratings: temp });
  } else {
    // removing value
    setFilter({
      ...filter,
      ratings: [...filter.ratings.filter((v) => v !== e.target.value)]
    });
  }
};
```

Finally, when you use `.map` on `hotelRooms` you can filter the list before mapping it.

```js
{hotelRooms
  .filter((h) => filter.ratings.includes(h.hotel.starRating))
  .map((h) => (
    <div key={h.hotel.name}>
      stuff
    </div>
  ))
}
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-dust-w9k2b)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was clearly beyond my understanding and am I correct I can apply the same logic to a second input for example I also need to filter it by occupancy. So, would approach this in the same way as you did ?

Comment: @shar27 yes, you can add the property `occupancy` in the `filter` state directly.. Don't call `.filter` twice, put all the logic inside the one that's already there :) [You can also define the filtering callback outside the render for better code readability]

Comment: like this ? .filter((h,room) => filter.ratings.includes(h.hotel.starRating)) && (extra.occupancy.includes(room.occupancy.maxAdults)) because this is throwing errors

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-orla-0pbob?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want it to re-render after you update hotelRooms? If this is correct, when you first render it, the value is [], a blank array. And in here :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchHotels()
}, [])
```

That last bit [], runs once after rendering. Therefore in your case (if my assumption is correct), you will want to change it to, as you want it to re-render each time hotelRooms value change

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchHotels()
}, [hotelRooms])
```

Comment: My question is how would I set my input checkbox to change what is displayed ?

Comment: I can do it via a console.log and onClick but I can't change the div contents

Comment: Sure yeah, that's a different question completely. But a small pointer, you want to have a function to handle the change in onChange... => <input value={"1"} type="checkbox" onChange={somethinghereyouneedtoadd}/>